# Measure the length using the Raycast and Triangular functions, Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, trigonometry, raycasting

I am developing AR in a mobile environment by using Unity.

[image]
* top and bottom have changed :)

The current procedure is as follows:

**1. Measure the slope of the mobile device.**

```
float angle = Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
```

**2. Shoot the Ray towards the surface at two points on the mobile screen** (Top, Bottom)

- The x coordinates of the two points are the same
- The y coordinates are the top and the smaller is the Bottom.

  ```
  Vector3 Top = hitTop.Pose.position;       
  Vector3 Bottom = hitBottom.Pose.position;
  ```

**3. Measure the height difference between a mobile device and its surface**(Y-axis)

```
Vector3 CameraPoint = Camera.main.transform.position;
Vector3 SurfacePoint = new Vector3(CameraPoint.x, Bottom.y, CameraPoint.z);
float H = CameraPoint.y - SurfacePoint.y;
```

**4. Measure the length of the horizontal to take advantage of the proportional expression.**

```
float W = Vector3.Distance(Top, SurfacePoint); 
float w = Vector3.Distance(Top, Bottom);
```

**5. Using a proportional expression, calculate the height of the small triangle.**

> H:W = h:w  => H * w = W * h => ∴  h = (H * w) / W

```
float h = ((H * w) / W);
```

**6. With two lines(h,w) and the slope of the camera, I want to measure the length of the purple line.**

- Interpret this problem as a coordinate plane, and create an expression on the Hypotenuse

  > x/w + y/h = 1
- Using a straight slope, obtain a straight line expression.

  > y = tan(90-θ)x

These two expressions are as follows.

> x = 1/(1/w + tan(90-θ)/h)
>
> y = tan(90-θ)/(1/w + tan(90-θ)/h)

**7. To prevent an infinite number, tanθ was changed to cosθ, sinθ.**

```
* tanθ = sinθ / cosθ
* tan(90 - θ) = cosθ / sinθ
```

> x = 1/(1/w + cosθ/(h * sinθ))
>
> y = (cosθ/sinθ)/(1/w + cosθ/(h * sinθ))

**8. I made a simple change because the expression is too complex.**

```
var x = (h * w * Mathf.Sin(angle)) / (h * Mathf.Sin(angle) + w * Mathf.Cos(angle));

var y = (h * w * Mathf.Cos(angle)) / (h * Mathf.Sin(angle) + w * Mathf.Cos(angle));
```

**9. I measured the distance (0,0), (x, y)**

```
float Object_height = Vector2.Distance(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(x, y));
```

Currently, the desired length is measured by the above calculation method.
But it doesn't work properly.

**What I want is the length of purple.**

I only know the star-shaped coordinates, the slope of the camera, and the slope of the purple line.

The slope of the purple line is the same as that of the camera.

The picture below is a case of failure.

I think the greater the gap between red and yellow Ray, the more different the value.

Which part is wrong?

Tell me how I can use the trigonometric function to get the length of the purple line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved easily without any trigonometry, with help of Unity's Ray class/struct, which offers handy GetPoint(float distance) method.
Getting the distance from the camera to your near raycast is trivial ( .magnitude), than instead of doing the second raycast, its enough to create a ray, and query it for a point at the given distance. Getting the purple line's length from your example is just a matter of doing another .magnitude

```
    startPos=transform.position;    // to be replaced with camera position
    var hitpoint1=targetA.position; // to be replaced with raycasts hit1
    var hitpoint2=targetB.position; // to be replaced with reaycast hit2
    Ray rayB=new Ray(startPos,hitpoint2-startPos);
    float dist=(hitpoint1-startPos).magnitude;
    var purpleEndPoint=rayB.GetPoint(dist);

    Debug.Log("purple line length ="+(hitpoint1-purpleEndPoint).magnitude);
```

Comment: why use `float dist=(hitpoint1-startPos).magnitude;` and not `float dist=vector3.Distance(hitpoint1, startPos);`?

Comment: @akaBase one character less :) I believe the two calls do exactly the same thing

Comment: @zambari can't argue with efficiency!

Comment: @akaBase From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html): `Vector3.Distance(a,b) is the same as (a-b).magnitude` -> it is exactly the same

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, due to readability I prefer to use `Vector3.Distance(a,b)` but it is 6 of 1, half a dozen of the other :)